# Add copyright information to Sphinx documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx, copyright-display

I'm using Sphinx to document a Python module.

I have a module that has **author** and **copyright** defined.

```
__author__ = "John Doe <johndoe@example.com>"
__copyright__ = "Copyright 2015-2016 Dummy Corp All Rights Reserved."
```

I tried adding the :special-members: tag to the automodule directive.

```
.. automodule:: PyFabric
   :special-members:
```

This documents the author, but copyright isn't picked up. Is there anyway to get Sphinx to recognize and add the copyright?

Answer (score 2):

In your `conf.py`, set `copyright = "© 2042 The Ravenous Bugblatter Beast of Traal"`.

See [sphinx-doc documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/usage/configuration.html#confval-copyright).

At least for the `html_theme = "sphinx_rtd_theme"` that I use, this will add the copyright notice in the footer of every HTML page.

This does **not** add the copyright notice to latex (and PDF) generated documentation; there is a [open feature request](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2876) at the time of writing.  I have asked how this might be done nevertheless, see *[How to add copyright notice to sphinx-generated latex documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54147210/974555)*.

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx doesn't use those, does it?   https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/sphinx.html

```
moduleauthor:: John Doe <johndoe@example.com>
```

Anyway, sphinx doesn't have that as far as I've seen.

More python formating examples : [What is the common header format of Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523427/what-is-the-common-header-format-of-python-files)