# How to add copyright notice to Sphinx generated Latex documentation?

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, copyright-display

I have set the [`copyright` configuration value](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/usage/configuration.html#confval-copyright) and it correctly appears in the HTML output.  However, it does not appear at all in the LaTeX output, and I can't find any [option for LaTeX output](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/usage/configuration.html#options-for-latex-output) that will make it appear.

How can I automatically include the copyright notice in the LaTeX output, using Sphinx?  Of course, I could manually add it or write a small script to add it, but I expect it should be possible within the Sphinx framework.

Apparently, there is a [request for improvement](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2876) to make this easier.

Comment: Consider that LaTeX output is a single file, and therefore a copyright is necessary on only one page, just like any printed book. As such, create a file for copyright, license, and other meta information about the project.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a copyright on each page (after title page and its back), you can do it with this mouthful of LaTeX macros (and sorry, it will ignore the `copyright` config value)

```
latex_elements = {
    'preamble': r'''
\makeatletter
   \fancypagestyle{normal}{
% this is the stuff in sphinx.sty
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{{\py@HeaderFamily\thepage}}
% we comment this out and
    %\fancyfoot[LO]{{\py@HeaderFamily\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}
    %\fancyfoot[RE]{{\py@HeaderFamily\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
% add copyright stuff
    \fancyfoot[LO,RE]{{This is \textcopyright\ 2019, Sphinx Team.}}
% again original stuff
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{{\py@HeaderFamily \@title\sphinxheadercomma\py@release}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    }
% this is applied to each opening page of a chapter
   \fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{{\py@HeaderFamily\thepage}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
% add copyright stuff for example at left of footer on odd pages,
% which is the case for chapter opening page by default
    \fancyfoot[LO,RE]{{This is \textcopyright\ 2019, Sphinx Team.}}
    }
\makeatother
''',
}
```

For more info on the LaTeX syntax see [fancyhdr docs](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). You have to LaTeX-escape yourself any worrisome character like `$`.

Since Sphinx 1.8.3, you can put LaTeX material directly on back of title page (for `'manual'` docclass, as there is no such notion for `'howto'`  docclass) via `\sphinxbackoftitlepage` which is optional LaTeX macro you can define in `'preamble'` or `'maketitle'`. See [docs](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.8/usage/configuration.html?highlight=sphinxbackoftitlepage#confval-latex_elements) (you need to scroll down to `'maketitle'`).

It seems to make indeed better sense to issue the copyright only at one location, so why not at back of title page as it is left empty by default. (`'manual'` docclass)