# Where to add __author__ in Python Packages

Tags: python, metadata, docstring

I'm writing a simple Python package with (currently) only one module.

Where should I put the docstring and `__author__` meta attributes? Do they go in the `__init__.py` or in each modules?

Is there a PEP pertaining to this? I was only able to find the generic docstring one, which doesn't answer this question.

Comment: Maybe, this could to help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523427/what-is-the-common-header-format-of-python-files

Comment: That's why a package with only one module is a bad idea. It only serves to create spurious problems like this.

Comment: @Goyo *Currently*. Ignoring a future desire for packaging because of documentation styling is short sighted and naive.

Comment: @Milk Actually ignoring future desires and concentrate on current requirements is widely regarded as good practice in software development, according to my perception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Honestly I will put the author in the `setup.py` file if you have one. This way you didn't pollute all the files in the project with duplicated information.

But if you want to do it you can follow this structure http://web.archive.org/web/20111010053227/http://jaynes.colorado.edu/PythonGuidelines.html#module_formatting

Comment: I didn't have a setup.py. This seems like the best answer. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

According to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#module-level-dunder-names):

> Module level "dunders" (i.e. names with two leading and two trailing underscores) such as **all** , **author** , **version** , etc. should be placed after the module docstring but before any import statements except from **future** imports.

So I would suggest putting it before your import statements and after the docstring.