# Including metadata (author, copyright, license) in Python project

Tags: python, metadata, documentation, python-sphinx

I want to add the authorship information in the documentation. I'm using Sphinx to auto-generate docs from the code. I was wondering is it okay to simply use a single line comment at the start of the file or is there some other proper way to indicate authorship, copyright, License and acknowledgement info. I want it to be there in the code but maybe not visible in the Sphinx generated HTML.

Is there any PEP standard regarding this?

I saw this answer but I'm finding conflicting answers elsewhere - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1523456/21666103